# Datastax Opcenter Stop Errored: Timed out waiting for Cassandra to stop

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Am creating multi node cassandra cluster on ubuntu environment. I followed this article http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/how-to-set-up-and-monitor-a-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-linux and installed. With nodetool i can see all the nodes are up and running fine. But when i try to install opscenter for easy monitoring the cluster, I get

```
Error: Stop stage failed: Failed to stop node 172.18.250.13: Timed out waiting for Cassandra to stop.
```

I tried all the possible ways, Can anybody have knowledge about this problem Please..

Comment: Are you able to watch Opscenter dashboard in browser? if yes then click on "fix" link besides Cluster name in upper left corner,this will install Opscenter agent in other nodes,all nodes login id-password must be same , I followed this http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/agent/agent_auto

Comment: I can see, but when i click on dashboard it pop up an error message like Couldn't connect to cluster, when i click on cluster it pop up message like unrecognized cluster partition..

Comment: I cannot identify where you are actually stucked,at the end edit cluster option is there,enter node's ip addresses in that,Did you install Opscenter using this link?http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/install/install_deb after doing relevant changes restart ospcenter

Comment: Yes I tried the above article also, but no use same error.. It it don't pass stop phase.. It is the exact error message Error loading events: Unable to load /Test_Cluster/events?count=5&reverse=1 status:404

Comment: This is the error message when i click on ring view "Error loading cluster view: Unknown cluster partitioner"

Comment: sorry mate,I used aboeve link and set up it,just take a last chance by seeing that in /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf file, make sure ssl_port = 8443 line is uncommented.

Comment: Everything seems to fine, but still problem persists.. Anyhow thanks for your effort dude..